# Exasol: How to get the session queries executed in Exasol server

Tags: sql

I am have connect to Exasol server where queries are written in a reporting application. Now i want the list of queries executed in particular execution of my report.

Note: I am looking for tables or logs which holds the information of the executed application session after its execution also.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at tables EXA_DBA_AUDIT_SESSIONS and EXA_DBA_AUDIT_SQL in schema EXA_STATISTICS - these hold info about the session and the SQL that has been run. You may need to turn auditing on to tell the system to populate these tables.

There are many useful tables in EXA_STATISTICS giving info on resource usage etc.